# "Tightening up" a map in the fibre of a principal torus bundle

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology, fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

Suppose $p_1:E_1\to B$ and $p_2: E_2\to B$ are two compact principal $\mathbb{T}^d$-bundles over the same base $B$. Suppose there exists a fibre-preserving map $F:E_1\to E_2$ that covers the identity $\text{id}_B$, i.e., $p_2\circ F=\text{id}_b\circ p_1$.

By compactness then I think I could conclude that $F$ induces the same automorphism on the the first homology (and the fundamental group) of every $\mathbb{T}^d$ fibre, i.e., $F_b:p_1^{-1}b\to p_2^{-1}b$ on the first homology of $\mathbb{T}^d$ is the same matrix on $\mathbb{Z}^d\to\mathbb{Z}^d$ at every $b$.

Now I want to further assume that $(F_b)_*:\mathbb{Z}^d\to\mathbb{Z}^d$ is the identity.

Then I wonder if I could kind of "tighten this map up". More precisely, I wonder if I could find a map $G\simeq F$ such that $G(t.e)=t.G(e)$ where $t\in\mathbb{T}^d,\ e\in E_1$. That is, $F$ is homotopic to a map that is identity in the fibres. This in particular implies that $E_1$ and $E_2$ are isomorphic.

I think this might rely on the fact that $\mathbb{T}^d$ is a $K(\pi,1)$. I was trying to chase through long exact sequence but wasn't very successful.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: I believe what you are asking is equivalent to asking if $\operatorname{Homeo}(T^d) \simeq \operatorname{haut}(T^d)$.  The latter can be understood rather easily using the fact a torus is a $K(\pi ,1)$, the former I imagine is not understood if $d>2$, but probably it is well enough understood to answer the question in the negative.

Comment: @ConnorMalin Thanks for the reply! Is haut what you said same as the mapping class group? I wonder if $F$ give a section $B\to\text{Homeo}(\mathbb{T}^d)$ or something. I now kind of tend to believe it is true just by straight-line homotopy... What might go wrong in the process?

Comment: @ConnorMalin By the way have you ever seen any results where people computed $\text{Homeo}(\mathbb{T}^d)$? I tried to search but haven't seen any...

Comment: $\pi_0(\operatorname{haut})$ is the mapping class croup. $\operatorname{haut}$ is the space of self homotopy equivalences. I am sure it is easy to find references for $d=1,2$ but it is probably unknown after that.